# Why Does this Expression for a Probability Have Units?

Tags: electric-current, probability, dimensional-analysis, units, biophysics

In this paper titled "[Measurement of Photon Statistics with Live Photoreceptor Cells](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.2792)" the equation 3 which expresses a relation for the probability of a given photocurrent given a certain number of isomerizations reads:

$\tilde{P}(A|n)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi (\sigma_D^2+n\sigma_A^2)}}exp(-\frac{(A-n\bar{A_0})^2}{2(\sigma_D^2+n\sigma_A^2)})$

In this equation $n$, $A$, $\bar{A_0}$, $\sigma_A$ and $\sigma_D$ signify the number of isomerizations, amplitude of the photocurrent, average of the photocurrent amplitude, standard deviation of the photocurrent amplitude in response to a single isomerization and the standard deviation of the photocurrent in darkness, respectively. $n$ is just a number with no units but $A$, $\bar{A_0}$, $\sigma_A$ and $\sigma_D$ have the units of electric current.

As far as I know probabilities don't have units. As far as I see, the expression inside the exponent does not have units but the coefficient $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi (\sigma_D^2+n\sigma_A^2)}}$ has the units of $[I]^{-1}$ (inverse current). Hence, the whole expression for $\tilde{P}(A|n)$ has this unit. The question is, how can an expression for a conditional probability have units?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a probability, but a probability density. The probability of hitting a specific value $x$ of a continuous distribution is zero, but the probability of finding a value in interval $[x, x+dx]$ is finite and *dimensionless*:
$$
P(x<X<x+dx)=f(x)dx,
$$
where $f(x)$ is the probability density, which must have the units inverse of $dx$, to assure that the actual probability is dimensionless.

Comment: I made a rookie mistake! Thank you very much for the answer.